# How to know the background color of Pdf

Tags: iphone, pdf

Sometimes pdf might have a transparent background. And In my application I have given a option to choose background. So, in case of pdf with transparent background and background color black all things becomes black black so, any way to check or any key inside dictionary of pdf page that can help me?  Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution for you would be to remove black color from available background colors.

Generally, all pdf pages have transparent background and the white background color is set by the viewer application. It is possible to set a background color for each page.  You can read all about it in *Page Group* under *Transparency* section of the [PDF Reference](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf).
It is also possible to show a background color for a page by setting 'BoxColorInfo' dictionary in the page dictionary with appropriate values.

But I am not sure what you can achieve by knowing what color a page background is, since black background is going to be a problem for PDFs with transparent pages anyways.

**EDIT**: Following is the paragraph from PDFReference i was trying to point you to:

> Ordinarily, the page is imposed directly on an output medium, such as
>   paper or a display screen. The page group is treated as an isolated
>   group, whose results are then composited with a backdrop color
>   appropriate for the medium. The backdrop is nominally white, although
>   varying according to the actual properties of the medium. However,
>   some applications may choose to provide a different backdrop, such as
>   a checkerboard or grid to aid in visualizing the effects of
>   transparency in the artwork.

It says that most PDFs would have a transparent and it is your application which shows the background color. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Sorry for too late. I have checked your answer and pdf reference. But I am not getting to much from pdf reference. From pdf reference I got that 'BoxColorInfo' is option parameter. Can you tell me exact key name from which I can get idea about the page color. Really thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't think the `BoxColorInfo` dictionary does what the answer suggests.  Instead, the PDF spec states: "Interactive PDF processors may offer the ability to display guidelines on the screen for the various page boundaries. The optional BoxColorInfo entry in a page object [... specifies ...] the colours and other visual characteristics to be used for such display."